# Firestore fetching all documents on a node.js server. Scalability

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-firestore

Every night at 12pm I am fetching all of the users from my firestore database with this code.

```
const usersRef = db.collection('users');
const snapshot = await usersRef.get();
snapshot.forEach(doc => {
    let docData = doc.data()
    // some code and evaluations
})
```

I just want to know if this is a reliable way to read through all of the data each night without overloading the system. For instance if I have 50k users and I want to update their info each night on the server, will this require a lot of memory server-side to do? Also, is there a better way to handle what I am attempting to do, with the generic premise of updating the users data each night.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is loading all documents in a collection in one go. Even on a server, that will at some point run out of memory.

You'll want to instead [read a limited number of documents](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/order-limit-data), process those documents, then read/process a next batch of documents, until you're done. This is known as [paginating through data with queries](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/query-cursors) and ensures you can handle any number of documents, instead of only the number that can fit into memory.